# AspectJ not executing the advice

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to understand how AspectJ works so I built this very simple example. I can execute x() from a web browser but applaud() never gets executed. Why? How can I get it executed (apart from calling it inside x())? I am trying to do all this without creating an xml.
My environment is Java, Spring, AspectJ, IntelliJ and Windows 10.

```
package hello;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Aspect
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SomeClass {

    @RequestMapping("/x")
    @Pointcut("execution(* hello.SomeClass.x())")
    public String x() {
        System.out.println("in x");
        return "<div><h1>Some content</h1></div>";
    }

    @After("hello.SomeClass.x()")
    public void applaud() {
        System.out.println("CLAPCLAPCLAPCLAPCLAP");
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you design the rest controller, configuration class and aspect all at once?

Comment: I don't know. I just wanted to have something very simple to play with. Are you suggesting it was a bad idea to do that?